# Installing Apache to CentOs 5.7 (problems with repo)

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos

I'm installing Apache on CentOS 5.7, I followed instructions here : 
 http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-apache-php-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/

I've installed this also :

Remi Dependency on CentOS 5 and Red Hat (RHEL) 5 ##

```
rpm -Uvh http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/5/i386/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
```

When I install this, there's warning:

```
/var/tmp/rpm-xfer.Bqu2xo: Header V3 DSA signature: NOKEY, key ID 217521f6
```

But it says that the package is alread installed.

Then I move on to 3rd steps:

```
yum --enablerepo=remi install httpd php php-common
```

But it says:

```
error getting repository data for remi, repository not found.
```

Why is it like that?

Comment: have you set enabled=1 switch in /etc/yum.repos.d/remi_repofile.repo ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install both these:

```
## Remi Dependency on CentOS 5 and Red Hat (RHEL) 5 ##
rpm -Uvh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/i386/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm

## CentOS 5 and Red Hat (RHEL) 5 ## 
rpm -Uvh http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-5.rpm
```

To get rid of the NOKEY warning when installing the EPEL repo, do this:

`rpm --import https://fedoraproject.org/static/217521F6.txt` to import the EPEL GPG key (Taken [here](https://fedoraproject.org/keys))

My guess is that you forgot to install the second RPM for Remi on CentOS 5, which is why it can't find it.

If you want to confirm it's been installed, look in /etc/yum.repos.d and look for a file for remi, than cat it. You should see a section called `[remi]` in it. Contrary to what kaji said, you do not need to enable it if you do it as a one-time shot with the --enablerepo=remi option...